# CiviCrm installation error on Drupal 9

Tags: drupal, error, civicrm-entity

After installation of the 'drupal/civicrm_entity:^3.3'. I got error 500. When I tried "update.php" get the following error.

`Warning: require_once(DB/DataObject.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in require_once() (line 26 of vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/DAO.php).`

Can anyone help me, please?
I have updated drupal core. I tried to remove the module via composer. I could not remove the module as well.

Comment: What version of CiviCRM?

Comment: I suspect that the $civicrm_root variable is not set to the right local of the CiviCRM codebase in the civicrm.settings.php .. should be set to [codebase-root]/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core